# Using ajax to get form confirmation page. Laravel 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I have created this form and instead of submitting the form to get the conformation page, I want to use ajax. The senario: You are on the create page, then when you submit it asks you to conform but that is another page. How to get the confirm page to pop up as a modal on the create page?

The create form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="GET" action="{{ action('JobsController@confirm') }}">

// contents

//submit button
</form>
```

I dont know how to use ajax with form requests. Could you provide a place to read up on so next time I'll know what do try before asking a question without first trying something? Thanks.